# Jquery script to soft scroll to anchors breaking links on page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

my jquery that I am using to to "soft scroll" down the page when hitting a link seems to be breaking all links on the page. I just noticed this why developing the site. Here is my jquery.

```
/*-------------------
ANIMATION SCROLLING TO CATEGORYS ON PAGE
---------------------*/
var $root = $('html, body')

$(document).on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 750);
    return false;
});
```

If I remove this code, everything on the site works fine.

When I put this code back in, the soft scrolling works to anchors on the page, but it breaks all links on my page. Whether it's to a releative link on my site or to an external link. Clicking on any links on the page does nothing, like there not even links anymore.

Does anyone know why this could cause all my links to not work?

---

### UPDATE

---

I got this to work my changing my internal links and adding a class to them.

```
<a href="#cats" class="internal">
```

And then changed the javascript to

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.internal', function (event)
```

My original code canceled all default behavior to all links on the page. Updated answer thanks to GentlemanMax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to every single link on your page when you do:

```
$(document).on('click, 'a', function(event){...
```

You are saying something like "When someone clicks any `a` tag in the document, do this thing.  Since the first line of your callback is `event.preventDefault()`, the default link behavior is prevented.  You need to filter your event binding to only prevent normal link behavior on your internal links.

If it is possible, your best option is to add a class to your internal links so that you can change your function to something like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.internal-page`, function(event){...
```

If that isn't a possibility, you can do some logic on the `href` attribute of the clicked link to confirm that it is internal before calling `event.preventDefault()`.